# how can I integrate the existing project written in C with the iphone view-based application project?

Tags: iphone, c, project, integrate

I would like to ask that if I have a project written in C and another project of view-based iphone application. How can I access that C methods, properties from the C library while I am working in the iphone project, I mean, how can I use the C project in iphone app?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the library, is it compiled in binary? do u have the source code? do you have the interfaces ".h" files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C APIs can directly be called from Objective-C, there are no special tricks required - just like C, #include the header file and call the function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to mention before that the C project I use is a third party C project, and I need to use it in my iphone application, like accessing its method, properties, etc.